# Pause a video in a recyclerView when it is a certain percentage on the screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to play a video when its view is 75% on the screen inside of the recyclerView adapter. So findFirstVisibleItem and all those would not work here. (Or if they do, I have no idea how they would work).

Currently I am waiting for views to be recycled before I am able to pause or play a video, but this begins the moment a new view is generated. Can anyone please help I have been researching this for very long and have gotten no where.

Comment: ok I go it You want to pause video and then play it.? again from where it is paused.? @Janwilx72

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is use a `**Model Class**`.!

```
        Class Video{

        String videoUrl;   //Http://
        int videoDrawable; //R.id.video
        String videoName=;
        boolean isplaying=flase;
        boolean ispuase=false;
        int lastDuration=0;



        //Constructors

        gettter and setter  here.!

        }
    ///////////////////
    Class AdapterClasss{
     int lastpostion=-1;
    VideoView videoView ;

     public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

    videoView =(VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);  
    playBtn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    pauseBtn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.pauseBtn);
    }
```

now in Your `Adapter Class` do few changes in `onBindViewHolder`

```
         @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

                final Video videoObj= videoList.get(position);
    /Creating MediaController 

    holder.playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

            MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);  
                mediaController.setAnchorView(holder.videoView);  

         //specify the location of media file  
               Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+
    "/media/"+videoObj.getvideoName()+".mp4");          


                  //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView  
               videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);  
               videoView.setVideoURI(uri);          
               videoView.requestFocus();  
   lastpostion=position;

     if(videoObj.getisPuase())
    {
    //now here you have to set your duration fro where you want to start your video 


if(videoView.ispause())
{
               videoView.start();  
            videoObj.setisPlaying(true);
 notifyItemChanged(position);
}

    }else if(videoObj.getisPlaying()!=true)
        {
      videoView.start();  
            videoObj.setisPlaying(true);
 notifyItemChanged(position);

}

    }


    holder.pauseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


       int duration = videoView.getDuration();
        videoView.pause();
        lastDuration.setLastDuration(duration);
        videoObj.setisPlaying(false);
         videoObj.setisPlaying(true);


    }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.

ItemDecoration is called multiple time while rendering the recycler's content so it is not supposed to do heavy stuff here, but you can use it to notify when some percentage of the view is visible.

ItemDecoration have several methods, but the one you need to implement is:

```
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, State state);
```

or maybe

```
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, State state);
```

For the case you are asking for you will notice no  difference, but to complement the explanation the first one is called when your row is rendered on the screen so you could paint "over" it and the second one is called before the row is rendered so you can paint something "below".

For this case you don't need to paint anything, just to calc the size of your view. For that mission you need to get the rendering views, and detect which one is the one with the video.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount - 1; i++) {
    View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
    int adapterPos = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
    int viewType = parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(adapterPos);
    ... Your code here ...
    // if(viewType == THE_EXPECTED_TYPE) {
    //     if(child.top() == parent.top()) {
    //         notifyViewIsVisibleAt100(); //100%; make your calcs to ensure your 75%
   //      }
   //  }
    }
}
```

You need to register the ItemDecoration to the recyclerView at first.

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(theItemDecoration);
```

Comment: I know I have already assigned the bounty to you @jDur , But can you please help me with the calculations part. I am struggling to visualise what to use that would show whether or not it is 75% in screen

Comment: @Janwilx72  I'd probably try using top of the views to do the calcs. Take in mind top property represents pixel position in Y axis relative to the parent, so child.getTop() should be negative when it is not fully showed and >= 0 when it is showed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your recycle view scroll listener on ScrollStatechanged:

```
if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
                int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                Video video;
                if (urls != null && urls.size() > 0)
                {
                    if (findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
                        //handle here to play video in adapter
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       //code here for another position
                    }
                }}
```

Comment: How do I then access the video that is passed on in the viewHolder to the adapter at the certain position to attempt to pause it

Comment: onBindViewHolder() check item on that position and create a method to pause and play video

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try this, its worked for me;

https://github.com/eneim/Toro

[image]